# Keycloak on Kubernetes error to access admin

Tags: kubernetes, devops, keycloak

I created a `keycloak` with `k8s yml`, but i'm got the issue when i try to access the `admin`

`Refused to frame 'http://keycloak.mydomain.com.br/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".`

My DNS is running with `SSL` but the `keycloak` is loading some scripts with `http` insted of `https`. I tried a lot of solutions that i found but nothing worked.

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: portalbooking
  name: keycloak-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
          args: ["start-dev"]
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_URL
              value: https://keycloak.mydomain.com.br
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
              value: keycloak.mydomain.com.br
                # - name: KC_PROXY_SCHEME
                #value: https
            - name: KC_PROXY_NAME
              value: keycloak.mydomain.com.br
                # - name: KC_HOSTNAME
                #value: "keycloak.mydomain.com.br"
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              value: h2
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
              value: "80"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
              value: "443"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_OPTS
              value: "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile=preview -Dkeycloak.auth.server.url.https=${KEYCLOAK_URL}"

              
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: portalbooking
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: portalbooking
  name: keycloak-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/content-security-policy: "frame-src 'self' keycloak.mydomain.com.br"   
spec:
  rules:
    - host: keycloak.mydomain.com.br
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: keycloak-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: What happens when you set the following annotation on your ingress? `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`

Comment: @Elazar nothing different. Same issue.

Comment: @Elazar sorry. I tested it, and now i can't open my keycloak i got another error `redirected you too many times`

Comment: You should disable the ingress for now. access via the service and set `proxy-address-forwarding parameter=true` via realm-settings. When this is complete add the following annotations
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify: "off"`
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-headers: "X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Forwarded-For"`

Comment: @Elazar how can i do that?